# Drag and Drop Imageview

Tags: android

I am trying to create a drag and drop imageview. I have used the same code as in this link http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_drag_and_drop.htm. I can drag the image but while dropping, the imageviewbecomes invisible. Can someone help me?

This is my java code.

```
package com.example.draganddropbutton;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ClipData;
import android.content.ClipDescription;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.DragEvent;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ImageView img;
    String msg;
    private android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        img=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        img.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                ClipData.Item item = new ClipData.Item((CharSequence)v.getTag());
                String[] mimeTypes = {ClipDescription.MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN};

                ClipData dragData = new ClipData(v.getTag().toString(),mimeTypes, item);
                View.DragShadowBuilder myShadow = new View.DragShadowBuilder(img);

                v.startDrag(dragData,myShadow,null,0);
                return true;
            }
        });

        img.setOnDragListener(new View.OnDragListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
                switch(event.getAction())
                {
                    case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
                        layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)v.getLayoutParams();
                        Log.d(msg, "Action is DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED");

                        // Do nothing
                        break;

                    case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
                        Log.d(msg, "Action is DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED");
                        int x_cord = (int) event.getX();
                        int y_cord = (int) event.getY();
                        break;

                    case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED :
                        Log.d(msg, "Action is DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED");
                        x_cord = (int) event.getX();
                        y_cord = (int) event.getY();
                        layoutParams.leftMargin = x_cord;
                        layoutParams.topMargin = y_cord;
                        v.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                        break;

                    case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION  :
                        Log.d(msg, "Action is DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION");
                        x_cord = (int) event.getX();
                        y_cord = (int) event.getY();
                        break;

                    case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED   :
                        Log.d(msg, "Action is DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED");

                        // Do nothing
                        break;

                    case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                        Log.d(msg, "ACTION_DROP event");

                        // Do nothing
                        break;
                    default: break;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });

        img.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
                    View.DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(img);

                    img.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, img, 0);
                    img.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });



    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

This is my xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.example.edusys.draganddropbutton.MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Drag and Drop Example"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textSize="30dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Tutorials Point"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    android:textColor="#ff14be3c" />>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView2" />
```

Comment: you are not doing anything on drag end .do you are image showing stuff on drag end

Comment: `img.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);` on touch down you are setting the view to invisible! remove this line

Comment: Try printing coordinates (x,y) of image through whole process, maybe it is places out of screen. Print coordinates of whole layout as well. Remember that you get coordinates of left top corner of view.

Comment: Muhammad Babar: If I remove that line, the app crashes when I touch the imageview. Already tried it.

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the visibility of the ImageView img as INVISIBLE when you start dragging, so you need to set it to visible when drag ends.

So add the following in you drag listener:

```
case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
  img.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
  break;
```

**Edit:**
also add

```
case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
  img.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
  break;
```

**Also note:**

You have set your drag on img, therefore whenever you drag out of the area of img, the drag ends abruptly. Consider adding the drag on the view/layout in which you want to drag the image.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: I thought of the same solution and tried already.. It's not working.